# Are FxCopAnalyzers and the .editorconfig file supposed to sync?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-analysis, fxcop, editorconfig

When I add an `.editorconfig` file to my project, it doesn't match the rules shown in the project's Dependencies > Analyzers.

For example, my `.editorconfig` file has this:

```
dotnet_diagnostic.CA2200.severity = error
```

Yet the analyzer shows this:

[image]

Are they supposed to sync? If not, what is the point of the `.editorconfig` file? When I compile, the rules in `Dependencies > Analyzers` seems to be followed. How am I supposed to use the `.editorconfig` file? This is confusing.

Ok, this is maddening. If I change the severity in the `.editorconfig` file, the compiler respects that and shows errors accordingly. That happens until I make a change in Dependencies > Analyzers, then THAT becomes the source of truth and the `.editorconfig` file is rendered moot at that point.

It looks like if I set a rule's severity, in Dependencies > Analyzers, to "Default," then the `.editorconfig` file takes over again.

Comment: They sync on my end. Do you have a ruleset file defined in your csproj? Look for `CodeAnalysisRuleSet`

Comment: I'm using `.editorconfig` instead of a ruleset. Apparently rulesets are now the old way. How do you sync? Do you manually do it, or does it happen automatically?

Comment: It happens automatically. As soon as I update the severity in the ux, it updates my editorconfig file. It is part of my solution (as a solution item), not sure if that has any impact

Comment: If you update your `.editorconfig` file, does that update show in `Dependencies > Analyzers`? And what do you mean it's a solution item?

Comment: Ah, you mean right-click the solution and add an item from there.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant

Answer (score 1):

I updated VS from 16.3.8 to 16.7.2. Now `.editorconfig` is the source of truth. I can no longer change the severity in the project's `Dependencies > Analyzers` (which is good).